# Why are properties like Controller.Request and Controller.Session not virtual?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection

Why are properties like [Controller.Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.request%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and [Controller.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.session%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) not virtual?

I bet it's staring me in the face and apologize if that's the case.

Here's what I've got, which I'm trying to improve. My `ControllerBase` allows me to inject mock/stubs/fakes (whatever) and I know this is a weak design and may lead to subtle bugs (nothing forces the use of the accessors for the dependencies).

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    private readonly ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary;
    private readonly HttpRequestBase request;
    private readonly HttpSessionStateBase session;

    public ControllerBase()
    {
        session = null;
        request = null;
        modelStateDictionary = null;
    }

    public ControllerBase(HttpSessionStateBase ssb, HttpRequestBase rq, ModelStateDictionary msd)
    {
        session = ssb;
        request = rq;
        modelStateDictionary = msd;
    }

    protected HttpSessionStateBase GetSession()
    {
        return session ?? Session;
    }

    protected HttpRequestBase GetRequest()
    {
        return request ?? Request;
    }

    protected ModelStateDictionary GetModelState()
    {
        return modelStateDictionary ?? ModelState;
    }
}
```

Comment: these are httpcontext variables. The engineers did not think you would want to override them. You can still MOQ them by creating empty equivalents.

Comment: do you write tests for controller, and is that what you do, use MOQ?  or am i on the wrong track trying to unit test MVC controllers?  it's really all in the context of trying to become a better tester/engineer...

Comment: maybe i should be unit testing all of the dependencies that I actually authored and viewing the controller as trivial glue code...

Comment: yes, you moq http objects and unit test controllers. all your instincts are right. you just need a guide. this one's old but a good starter. I'll see if I can dig up better. http://www.kevinrohrbaugh.com/blog/2009/9/18/mocking-httpcontext-with-moq.html

Comment: thanks for the pointers... may be some light at the end of the tunnel for me yet :)

Comment: always glad to help fellow new yawker